# PCManFM always pops under

Tags: linux-mint, window-management, pcmanfm

Whenever PCManFM opens (Linux Mint 18.1 MATE x64, set as default in the preferences), be it from "Show in Folder" from a download in Chromium, or simply clicking a quick launch icon, it opens underneath already-opened programs.

Why doesn't it open on top, like most normal programs do?